# Pasar el contenido de un DataGridView a un DataSet con un DataTable ya definido

Tags: c#

Tengo un `DataGridView` que alimento desde unos `TextBox` y necesito pasar el contenido del `DataGrid` a un `DataSet` con un `DataTable` previamente creado, he intentado castearlo de esta manera:

```
DataSet ds = (DataSet)dataGridView.DataSource;
```

Pero no funciona, quisiera saber si habrá alguna manera de hacerlo.

Comment: ¿Qué error te sale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muy buenas,

Si el objeto `DataSet` ya tiene creado un objeto `DataTable`, bastaria con enlazar dicho `DataTable` con el `DataGridView`.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        // Referenciamos el primer objeto DataTable
        // existente en el objeto DataSet
        //
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

        // Enlazamos el control DataGridView con el
        // objeto DataTable
        //
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Si hacemos esto,  conforme escribes datos en el control `DataGridView`,automáticamente se actualizarán en el objeto `DataTable` existente en el objeto `DataSet`.

Espero que te sirva.